# Symfony 6 fetching objects without a controller

Tags: php, symfony

In previous versions of symfony, you could fetch objects like this
`

```
public function someMethod()
{
    $method = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Method::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => 1));


    return $method;
}
```

`
This was easy because it meant that you could easily make global variables in the twig.yaml file and have dynamic content all around your page.

Now in symfony as far as i know, an argument of ManagerRegistry has to be passed as a argument all the time. Am I being too close minded or is there a work around for this problem?

I tried extending classes and have it pass down that way but it gave me the same workaround errors.

Comment: Perhaps not close minded so much as confused?  It's not at all clear how the getDoctrine method made it easy to create global variables for twig.yaml files? Or what that even means.  The replacement code looks like `someMethod(EntityManagerInterface $em) { $method = $em->getRepo...`.

Comment: @Cerad could you write that line of code out? Because it looks like a still have to put a argument through the function

Comment: Hmmm.  Lets back up a moment.  Prior to Symfony 6 the base controller class has a getDoctrine method commonly used to get the entity manager.  That method was removed in Symfony 6 thus requiring that you inject the entity manager into either a controller action method or the constructor.

Comment: However, the getDoctrine method was not available to other non-controller services unless the developer chose to explicitly add it.  Maybe your predecessor did just that and maybe it stopped working because the entity manager service is now private.  Hard to tell without an error message.  In any event, you should be injecting the entity manager into the constructor of any non-controller service that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

In a controller you can do either this :

```php
class MyController extends AbstractController {
    
    private EntityManagerInterface $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
         $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

or

```php
class MyController extends AbstractController {
    { ... }
    public function someMethod(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $em->getRepository(SomeClass::class)
    }
}
```

I took a controller as an example but you can do this into your services. If you work with multiple entity manager, you can use the [ManagerRegistry](https://github.com/symfony/doctrine-bridge/blob/6.1/ManagerRegistry.php) that extends [AbstractManagerRegistry](https://github.com/doctrine/persistence/blob/3.0.x/src/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php) and use the method `getManager($name)`

There is no real workaround for this as you always need to inject it. Depending on what you want to achieve, may be there is solution that can help.

Answer (score 0):

you can also directly inject the repository:

```
public function someMethod(EntityRepository $repository) {
        $entities = $repository->findAll();
    }
```

and of course you can inject it in the construct as well:

```
class MyController extends AbstractController {
    
    private EntityRepository $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $repository) {
         $this->repository = $repository;
    }
}
```

if you are on php 8 you can write:

```
class MyController extends AbstractController {
    
    public function __construct(private EntityRepository $repository) {}
}
```